# Tomcat 8.5 Java 8 Out of Memory Error After Introducing Redis for Session Management

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory, redisson

I have a Java 8 application deployed on Tomcat 8.5, which has been running smoothly until recently when Tomcat abruptly stopped. After examining the logs, I identified an "out of memory" error:

```
java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x100dca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
```

The application had been functioning correctly until now, and the only major change was the introduction of Redis for user session management, utilizing the Redisson library. Redis is installed on the same physical server where the Tomcat application resides. The application is allocated the majority of the available memory, leaving approximately 2 GB for everything else.

On the first day of the crash, I noticed that the garbage collector was releasing memory, but the jvm crashed anyway.
[image]

[image]

On the second day, this was the state of Old Gen heap usage:

[image]

And this was the GC activity:

[image]

It appears that there were no major garbage collections despite memory approaching its limit.

I'm trying to understand if this is a problem related to sharing the server resources between Tomcat and Redis or if it's potentially a memory leak within the application. Any insights or suggestions on how to diagnose and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a profiler to see what's taking so much memory, or take a heap dump and analyze that.

Comment: Actually the app uses normally uses a lot of memory, but It didn't crash until I made this change

Comment: That's not a very nice or useful answer, are you suggesting that I should never make changes on my app?

Comment: Actually it is an interesting detail, the same app is replicated in other servers without using redisson (the only change so far) and in those servers is working fine. So mostly it is a problem with that last change. I'm trying to understand if it is memory leak problem or something else. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem 4 years ago doing the same user session management in Redis, and I think the client library, specifically Netty, was using non-heap memory.

Also, when stuff starts to use non-heap memory, you may want to lower the allocation of tomcat, so it doesn't trigger that OOM-killer thread you saw the OS invoke to protect the kernel. The fix for oom-killer issues is opposite what you might think, and you need to reduce JVM allocation, to allow more memory for the OS/kernel.

Comment: How do you solve it? 
Did you limit the direct memory that netty can use?

Comment: Well, a co-worker worked on it directly, but we ended up forking the redid-session-manager code, and limited the size of object we would save in certain use cases. But, this was 4 years ago, and there might be a better solution today.
Also, make sure your redis dependency versions are in-line with other dependencies, so it's not being downgraded, or upgraded, such that you have mis-matched client/netty code. That can also play into things somewhat.